# Nesting Open Office XML

Tags: html, xml, ms-word, ms-office

In html you can easily do the following:

```
<span id="outsideSpan">
    <span id="insideSpan>
       Some Text
    </span>
</span>
```

The innerHTML of a span can be any non-blocking html element.  In open office XML there isn't a natural "inner html" between run tags.  But we might think of the  tag as being SIMILAR in that it holds the "content" of the run.  My question is, can I do the following?

```
<w:r>
    <w:t>
         <w:hyperlink r:id="rId4">
             <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>Google</w:t>
             </w:r>
         </w:hyperlink>
    </w:t>
</w:r>
```

Would that validate for any arbitrary "parent w:t" element?

**Background**: my goal here is actually sort of backwards to the example.  I ultimately want to programatically alter an existing Word document so that an arbitrarily selected run is "surrounded" with a hyperlink.

Comment: Tags such as `<w:t>` are used in [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML), not in [OpenOffice.org XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org_XML).  Please fix the title and remove the openoffice.org tag.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, you can't do what you posted in your question because that would not be valid according to the Office Open XML schema.

What you need to do in order to insert a hyperlink is that you need to [break up the existing run into multiple runs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2009/06/29/splitting-runs-in-open-xml-word-processing-document-paragraphs/) and add a hyperlink element at a higher level (and not below a `w:t` element):

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:lang w:val="en-US" />
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:lang w:val="en-US" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is a link to the </w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:hyperlink r:id="rId4" 
        xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
    <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink" />
        <w:lang w:val="en-US" />
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t>Google</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:hyperlink>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:lang w:val="en-US" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> web site.</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```